# How to clone git clone git://kernel.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/linux.git behind proxy?

Tags: source-code

I'm not able to do a git clone `git://kernel.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/linux.git` behind proxy, even though I have configured my git for proxy.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I find it the easiest to clone via https behind a proxy. Cloning via ssh might not work because of a firewall.

Step 1:
Edit your gitconfig and add your proxy
`vim ~/.gitconfig`

```
[http]
   proxy = <protocol>://<domain>:<port>
```

Step 2:
Clone the Ubuntu kernel via https as mentioned in the Ubuntu [wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/SourceCode) on the section **"Obtaining the kernel sources for an Ubuntu release using git"**.

```
git clone https://git.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-kernel/ubuntu/+source/linux/+git/focal
```